# How to span a child div over two parent divs

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, gridview, marionette

**Background:**
I'm building a grid using the Backbone.MarionetteJS framework. I am however running into a specific issue which I'm unsure on how to solve.

**The code:**
My grid is build like the following:

```
<section>
    <div>
        <div class="day"></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div class="day">
            <div>
                <div id="c38" class="gridItem droppable ui-droppable">
                    <b>
                        <div id="c90" class="draggable orderItem stored ui-draggable" style="position: relative;"></div>
                    </b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="c39" class="gridItem droppable ui-droppable">
                    <b>
                        <div id="c91" class="draggable orderItem stored ui-draggable" style="position: relative;"></div>
                        <div id="c92" class="draggable orderItem stored ui-draggable" style="position: relative;"></div>
                    </b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

As you can see each div within the section contains a div with a class day. Day is in this case a horizontal grid row. A day has 7 droppable gridFields  with each their own ID. Each gridfield for that day can contain multiple items such as field C39.

**The problem:** Although the above code works well, it could occour that I have an item (let's take c92) that's not only placed in gridfield c39 for that specific day, but also in grid field c38. Rather then displaying the grid item twice (once in each grid field) it would be much neater to have this item span over both div's so it looks like a singular item that can be dragged and dropped afterwards again.

I have however no idea how to achieve this. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: I would love to but no. My hands are tied by the company I'm building it for. A working example is not explicitly nececary either. I'm trying to make it apear (or make it so) that div #c91 is not only in #39 but also in #38 as "one" item. Not two seperate div's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi again and sorry for my long absence. Below you find my question reformed with the answer to my question.

This code represents a row:

```
<div class="day"></div>
```

A row could have multiple collumns such as:

```
<div id="c39" class="gridItem droppable"></div>
```

Each column in turn could contain multiple items:

```
<div id="c91" class="draggable orderItem"></div>
<div id="c92" class="draggable orderItem"></div>
```

The DOM builds this as the code provided in the original question. Although this code works just find when using multiple items inside of a column, belonging to a row, it was required to have an order span over not one, but multiple columns.

My hope was merely to avoid using positioning on grid items do to the nature of scroll-bars and windows that could possibly resize. This seems however not possible.

To everyone running into simulair problems I recommend adding some sort of additional wrapper inside of your row (or use the actual row) as a starting point for the offset in positioning items on the screen so the actual code could end up like:

```
<div class="day"> <!-- row generated by framework -->
    <div class="event"> <!-- used as offset for positioning -->
       <div id="c39" class="gridItem droppable"> <!-- grid column -->
           <div id="c91" class="draggable orderItem" style="position: absolute; left:x; top:y;"></div>
           <div id="c92" class="draggable orderItem" style="position: absolute; left:x; top:y;"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you appending these div by backbone views. 
If you are doing it by backbone views then every view is by default wrapped by a 'div'. 
We can change it by adding tag parameter. Add tag: 'span'

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing. These are the div's that you can see above each .day and each .gridItem. I will try what you said and get back to this in a bit.

Comment: I'm able to change the div's into tag's using tagName (had to do a quick lookup through the documentation). I am still unsure on what to do next.

Although they are using span's rather then wrapped div's the original problem still remains?

Comment: i didnt get whats the issue now ? can you explain in bit more detail ?